# SQL Server INFORMATION_SCHEMA contents

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, information-schema

In most RDBMS, the meta-model is "self contained", which means that I can find out the model of the meta-model by browsing the meta-model itself. This doesn't seem to be the case with SQL Server. What I want to do is this:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'
```

That way, I can discover the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` schema itself.

Is there any grant/permission/login setting that I have to configure in order to make the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views be "self contained"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think this is possible.

The definition of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` view is

```
CREATE VIEW [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[TABLES]
AS 
SELECT
    DB_NAME()           AS TABLE_CATALOG,
    s.name              AS TABLE_SCHEMA,
    o.name              AS TABLE_NAME,
    CASE o.type
        WHEN 'U' THEN 'BASE TABLE'
        WHEN 'V' THEN 'VIEW'
    END             AS TABLE_TYPE
FROM
    sys.objects o LEFT JOIN sys.schemas s
    ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
WHERE
    o.type IN ('U', 'V')
```

so it pulls its information from `sys.objects` however this in turn contains nothing about the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` objects.

The metadata for these is accessed via `sys.system_objects` instead.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this. The `sys` schema is self-contained in the way I expected it. But I prefer using the more standardised `information_schema`, if possible.

Comment: @Lukas - Well I doubt that it will be possible because it isn't excluding these on the grounds of permissions or something it just simply isn't in the source data for the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sys.all_views

```
select SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id), name
from sys.all_views
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks. That would work as a workaround. But I'd really prefer to use the `information_schema` as that is more standardised across RDBMS

Comment: For suitably small values of "standardized". Doesn't run, or runs and returns no rows on every dbms here--SQL Server, Oracle, and PostgreSQL to name the three most popular.

Comment: @Catcall, you mean `information_schema` is not reliable on SQL Server? I'd be surprised... I agree Oracle doesn't have it, but Postgres does. So does HSQLDB (the most standard-adherent, I think), H2, MySQL (OK, quite a liberal interpretation of the standard)

Comment: All of them have some INFORMATION_SCHEMA views, but none of them return anything useful for the OP's query. PostgreSQL has the view, for example, but has no rows `WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'`.

Comment: I'm the OP :-) OK, you're right. But this works in Postgres 9.0: `select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'information_schema'` (not capital letters...)

Answer (score -1):

```
USE information_schema;
SHOW TABLES;

USE mysql;
SHOW TABLES ;
```

Comment: Thanks, this isn't about MySQL (which has a self-contained `information_schema`)... With SQL Server, the `USE` command is not for selecting schemata, but for selecting databases